# Deduplication tool for rsync?

Tags: rsync, backup, deduplication

Is there a Linux / Unix tool that does de-duplication similar to the way Veeam does it before compressing and sending a backup with rsync to a mirrored location?

Comment: If it's at all relevant [btrfs supports dedupe](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what Veeam is, but I've been recommending [Borg Backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) to people for a while, since I discovered it. It's certainly a deduplicating backup tool, but you don't need to use rsync with it. It has its own method of transport.

Comment: That looks very interesting. I was about to head off into the sunset with `duplicity` talking to a [Hubic cloud](http://hubic.com), but maybe I need to consider Borg instead.

Comment: Yes, Borg Backup is pretty cool, though it's mostly the work of one person, namely Thomas, so it has a bus factor of one. He's doing really good work, though, and pulling strongly ahead of the competition, imo. I hope he can find some more developers.

Comment: More like a bus factor of 3-4 now, not as bad as it used to be. :)

Borg does variable block size de-duplication, which means if you have similar, but not exactly the same files, borg will de-duplicate the parts of those files that are alike, even if those similarities are at different offsets.  Other file-level de-duplication systems would have to duplicate the entire files.

Comment: @tgharold You must know more than I do. The last time I checked it was still Thomas the one man army. So, who are the other active devs?

Comment: There's this page which shows [contributors](https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/graphs/contributors?from=2015-01-24&to=2016-04-03&type=c) within the last year or so.  Another way is to look at the pull request authors.  One day I'll learn enough Python to help...

Comment: @tgharold Hmm, well if Thomas were to disappear, at the very least, development would slow down severely. I doubt `anarcat` would be able or willing to continue at that pace. It's true that (looking at the recent commits) more contributors seem to have appeared recently. Hopefully Borg Backup is getting some traction.

Answer (score 0):

[Backshift](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/backshift/) looks like it would fit your requirement. I've not used it - but I do want to try it out. [How it works](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/backshift/documentation/for-all/how-it-works.html).

[Lessfs](http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/) also looks a good contender. Again, I've not used it but may give it a whirl.

Comment: `lessfs` looks more interesting since it's block-level dedupe rather than file-level.