# rdfind-like tool to sparsify rsync operations

Tags: rsync, backup, rsnapshot

I use `rsnapshot` to take regular, automated snapshots of the home directory on my desktop (which runs Ubuntu on `sda`) and save them to a spare internal harddrive (`sdb`). Occasionally, I manually copy (via `rsync`) the contents of `sdb` to an external USB SSD (call it `sdc`). `sdc` also contains older manual backups of my files which predate my adoption of `rsnapshot`, and thus there are a lot of files on `sdc` that are duplicates of the incoming `rsnapshot` files.

I recently discovered the `rdfind` tool (with the `-makehardlinks` option) which lets me greatly reduce the disk usage on `sdc` by running `rdfind` after I manually `rsync` snapshots from `sdb` to `sdc`. However, this entails redudant I/O operations, because I first `rsync` the files over from `sdb` (writing about 250 GB), *then* run `rdfind` (freeing nearly the same 250 GB).

In principle, it should be possible to run something like `rdfind` *before* `rsync` to check hashes and determine which files from `sdb` need to be written out and which can be hard links—but how?

- I am seeking generic solutions for the Linux ecosystem, but distro- or filesystem-specific answers are also welcome.
- My desktop runs Ubuntu 22.04 and both `sdb` and `sdc` use BTRFS.
- My question is distinct from this one because it concerns deduplication *between* the origin and destination, not just at the origin: [Deduplication tool for rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186004/deduplication-tool-for-rsync)
- I am aware of the implications of hardlinking files.

Comment: You sound like you're trying to reinvent `rsnapshot`? Or perhaps you could roll your own with `rsync --link-dest`?

Comment: Be aware that `rdfind` doesn't differentiate files with the same content but different metadata (permissions, ownerships, etc.). I've ended up using it in a script that postprocesses its output for "potential duplicates" and then compares metadata before deciding two or more files really are duplicates

Comment: Use ZFS? It has automatic deduplication.

Comment: Will it deduplicate an incoming file from a (non-ZFS) filesystem without first writing it out? My understanding was that deduplication on ZFS was a sort of "background process" that happens around I/O.